# Permissions For Site Contents Sprocket

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, site-contents

I have a SharePoint (2013) group set to "Read" permission at the site level, so now those folks are missing the sprocket to access site contents. I would like for users to be able to access site contents in the normal manner so that they can view all the content in Site Contents.

Is this possible in 2013 with out code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a link to the site content (maybe in the quick launch?) with the target tou your group. (so just they can see it).

This is the link to the site content:

```
http://yourSite/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really was hoping for the actual sprocket/site content link to work with some sort of permission modification.

Comment: AFAIK is not possible